# Oracle regex_replace ' from values

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help wit removing "'pp'" from search results which appear at the biginning of text. Values in search resuls contain spaces and also '. I need to remove only 'pp from bigginig

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like:

```
select regexp_replace(col, '^pp', '')
```

Or a `case` expression:

```
select (case when col like 'pp%' then substr(col, 3) else col end)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regular expressions and can use simple string functions.

If you want to use `SELECT` then:

```sql
SELECT value,
       CASE
       WHEN value LIKE 'pp%'
       THEN SUBSTR( value, 3 )
       ELSE value
       END AS replaced_value
FROM   table_name
```

Outputs:

> ```
> VALUE | REPLACED_VALUE
> :---- | :-------------
> pp123 | 123           
> pp1pp | 1pp           
> 123pp | 123pp         
> 12345 | 12345
> ```

and, if you want to `UPDATE` the table:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET   value = SUBSTR( value, 3 )
WHERE value LIKE 'pp%';
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | VALUE |
> | :---- |
> | 123   |
> | 1pp   |
> | 123pp |
> | 12345 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=973f0f670beeefbccaf4cc23fb20d32a)*